# Do Removed / Deleted WordPress Widgets Are Lost Forever?

Tags: mysql, web, robots.txt, wordpress

If a person has some important text on a widget and accidentally he removes/deletes the widget by expanding it and clicking delete in wp-admin widget's area. Then do this mean that the widget has been lost forever?

Do widget resides somewhere in any of the mysql database's table? Are there any revisions of widgets available?

Another way to get the text is to search the web caching engines like Google Cache, Wayback Machine etc. But what if we are unlucky enough that we have not allowed web crawler in robots.txt file?

Update  (August 21, 2013) :-

Besides you give a general answer. Also state whether I can recover a simple 'text/html widget' that comes along with WordPress? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the widget:
the widget developer decides where and how to store the widget data and if that data has revisions or not.
At this point you have the fallowing options:
1) access your database and have a look in the "_options" table for for the option_name %LIKE% widget -> it will show you all the data you have saved related to that widget, if you don't find what you are looking for:
2) check the php code of the widget to see if you can find where it saves the data and if it has revisions.

Your best luck is to have the data in the "_options" table and if you have backup of the table you can extract the data from there.

Comment: what about a simple 'text/html widget' that comes along with WordPress?